# What is the extent of control over a kitsune?

Tags: mythical-creatures, japanese, shinto

Kitsune have something called a [Hoshi no tama](http://www.mythicalcreaturesguide.com/page/Kitsune), star ball or kitsune ball. They are white and/or gold orbs. The orb is like a kitsune's life force so they [hide it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kitsune), usually in their mouths or on their tails. If someone manages to get a hold of the orb, they have control over the kitsune.

What is the extent of that control? Could one keep a kitsune until they die and the kitsune reclaim the ball?

Comment: It's called a Hoshibana. I used to know more about this but i would have to go dig through notes

Comment: @EvilJinious1 I looked that up and got a kite festival. I added kitsune and got... other things

Comment: sorry, I was in a hurry and misspelled. It is a Hoshi no tama (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kitsune#Hoshi_no_tama)

Answer (score 1):

If the fox has a "ball" in it's mouth it is actually the female incarnation of a fox.  The male fox incarnation has a parchment or key in his mouth.  The "ball" is actually the pill of immortality.  The parchment/key is the contract a mortal agrees to with the foxes. Since foxes are shapeshifters, they can appear as female or male.  This duality is congruent with the principles of Yin/Yang.  You don't control foxes unless you are a Taoist/Shinto fox master.  You have an agreement with them. This agreement allows the mortal the opportunity to develop their soul in this life.

The Center For Traditional Taoist Studies published a 3 volume set on Fox lore called: The Tao of Celestial Foxes-The Way to Immortality. It has an extensive bibliography to say the least